# Where to find "jersey" for creating a java REST Service?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to build a java REST Service.

I am following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#first) tutorial (which seems to be extremely popular) and the 1st thing it says , is download *jersey* from this link : http://jersey.java.net/

However the link doesnt work , and even when i google more , i cant find anywhere a place to download these jar files that are essential to build the Service.

Any ideas where i can find it?

Comment: What do you mean by the "link doesn't work", you mean it's down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the jars from...

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjerseyjar.htm
```

Although I'd recommend using maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What is maven dependencies though?

Comment: There is the pom.xml here: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/

Comment: Maven is a way of managing jar files so you don't need to keep hunting them down, you can just put it in your xml an maven will download them for you :)

Comment: hmm maybe this way is better , cause i download the jar from the link and i get many errors on imports that i shouldnt get errors.. Maybe there are some files missing or something.. In what XML do i add these lines of code? I created a dynamic web project , but theres no XML file there.

Comment: create a pom.xml, best to install m2eclipse in Eclipse (have a quick google), then right click your project and do "convert to maven project" - it'll create a pom.xml for you.  I'd recommend doing like a hello world of Maven just to get the hang of it.